# How do I add programmatically-generated new files to source control?

Tags: version-control, frameworks

This is something I've never really understood about source control, specifically Subversion (the only source control I've ever used, which isn't saying much).  I'm considering moving to git or Mercurial, so if that affects the answer to my question, please indicate as such.

Ok.  As I understand it, every time I create a new file, I have to tell SVN about it, so that it knows to add it to the repository and place it under control.  Something like:

```
svn add newfile
```

That's fine if I'm the one creating the file: I know I created it, I know its name, I know where it lives, so it's easy to tell SVN about it.

But now suppose I'm using a framework of some kind, like Rails, Django, Symfony, etc., and suppose I've already done the initial commit.  All of these frameworks create new files programmatically, often many at once, in different directories, etc. etc.  How do I tell the source control about these new files?  Do I have to hunt each one of them down individually and add them?  Is there an easier way?  (Or am I possibly misunderstanding something fundamental about source control?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, you shouldn't add files to source control if they can be generated from other files in your project.  It's true that in some cases, a file is initially generated, but must be modified manually.  In that case you will have to add it to source control.  However, you should almost never automatically add files.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Matthew in general, if it can be generated it shouldn't be added but remain dynamically created.

For the practical question of adding multiple files, I don't remember in svn (though I think it should be possible), but to do this in git:

- Using git bash (command line) you can add all "loose" files under the directory or subdirectory by not specifying a file after the add command. You can also set git to ignore certain files, so they wont be added in that case.
- Another way is using git gui, it displays all un-tracked files and you can select them all (or groups of it) and add them in one click.